# How to auto populate alert message for opportunity closed under a custom object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagemessages

I am having one custom object "Site" which has lookup relationship with opportunity. Which means each site record has more than one opportunity. For example if a site record has 5 opportunity in that 4 opportunity has already closed then when i am trying to close the last opportunity in that site record it must display a alert message " your opportunity is closed, would you like to close the site record also yes or no". If i press yes means it must go to that particular site record their we can manually close the site record.

Comment: are you using a Vf page for the opportunity?

Comment: @Prady, thanks for the reply. No i am not using VF page for Opportunity

Comment: @LavanyaSanathkumar:  What is it that you have tried??

Comment: @LavanyaSanathkumar i am afraid, that might not be possible.. I hope somebody has a workaround for it.. Yes you could do all these using VF page on opportunity but in a standard page i dont think its possible

Comment: @Prady, after creating a site record i am having a custom button "Create OPP" which will create  a new opportunity under that site record.

Comment: I really don't think this will be possible without a VF page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to need a VF page for this on the opportunity record.  You just have to write a custom controller to display a pageMessage when all the opportunities are closed.  Something like this:

```
Integer numNonClosedOpps = [select count() from Opportunity where Site__c = :siteId and StageName != 'Closed' and Id != :thisOppId];
if (numNonClosedOpps == 0) {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 
        'All opps closed in this site.  Please <a href="urlforsite">go here</a> to close the site.'));
}
```

Within your vf page, you just need to add the pageMessages tag. Make sure to add the escape attribute to get your url to show up correctly:

```
<apex:pageMessages escape="true"/> 
<apex:detail/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this idea on the IdeaExchange: [Warning messages](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bra7AAC). Go vote now!